# Threading in C# , value types and reference types clarification?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stack

*After reading Jon Skeet [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/)  , and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx) article from msdn , I still have a question*

Let's say I have this code :

```
  MyPerson mp = new MyPerson(); //Field

  int g=0; //Field

  public void DoWork ()
   {
      int i;
      MyPerson mp2 = new MyPerson();  
      ...
   }
```

Now let's say I have 2 threads. which runs `DoWork`. ( let's ignore for now , race conditions)

- Will they both see the same `g` or each thread will have its own item ? ? ( value )
- Will they both see the same `mp`  or each thread will have its own item ?? ( instance )
- Will they both see the same `i` or each thread will have its own item ? ( value )
- Will they both see the same `mp2` or each thread will have its own item ? ( instance )
- if they both see the same  , why would I need `static` ?

*I've searched a lot about this topic , and **couldn't** find **any** article which states : Different Threads ,ref types  and value types...  )*

Comment: How is the class created by the calling thread code?

Comment: @asawyer just run in main 3 times `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork ),null);`

Comment: @RoyiNamir in the line above, the target instance is `this` each time - it is actually `new WaitCallback(this.DoWork)`. So if your code does that 3 times, then yes: they are 3 delegates targeting the same instance, so `mp` and `g` are shared **but** note what I was saying about changes not necessarily being observed unless you use a memory barrier (synchronization) or `volatile` access. For really complex reasons.

Comment: @MarcGravell but `writing` is not requires memory-barrier/lock/volatile. right ? only reading...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir depends on a lot of factors; for example, while yes: all writes are implemented as volatile writes, that is an implementation detail that shouldn't be used (when doing thread semantics, you care about what is **guaranteed**, and that: isn't). Also, it depends on the data size: `int`, `float`, etc, plus references are guaranteed to be atomic writes; but large structs (including `double` and `long`) are **not** guaranteed to be atomic writes. For primitives, `Interlocked` is handy for that; but otherwise: you'll definitely need synchronization to avoid torn values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither thread simply "runs `DoWork`"; they run `DoWork` *on a particular object*. If the two threads are created targeting different instances, then `mp` and `g` will be completely separate fields. If the two threads are created targeting the **same** instance, then `mp` and `g` will be shared *but* it is not guaranteed that the threads will see changes made by the other thread unless you use synchronization or `volatile` access.

For example:

```
var obj = new SomeObject();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(obj.DoWork);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(obj.DoWork); // clearly targeting the same instance
```

vs

```
var obj = new SomeObject();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(obj.DoWork);
obj = new SomeObject();
Thread thread2 = new Thread(obj.DoWork); // targeting a different instance
```

The local variables `i` and `mp2` are strictly specific to each thread.

Additional note: even if they are separate fields/locals, if some of the code in the `...` later reassigns `mp` or `mp2` to refer to *the same object*, then they will be squabbling over the same object; the same synchronization / `volatile` rules will apply.

Comment: Marc , Can you please explain _If the two threads are created targeting different instances_ ?

Comment: Basically, and in fact how it works internally, is the instance of the object is passed to the `DoWork` method as "`this`".  A nice way of visualising it I think.  (Under the hood, all instance methods on a class have a first parameter for '`this`')

Comment: @MarcGravell What if there is another method called `DoWork2()` which creates 2 threads which runs `DoWork()` . is it as the same as targeting the same instance explanation?

Answer (score 3):

The variables `g` and `mp` are 'global' to the containing class, so these will be the same objects seen by both threads. `i` is a local variable that is declared in the `DoWork` event; subsequently this will only be 'visible' to the background/alternative thread.

They don't 'see' the same, so the `static` keyword in this case has no relevence.

I hope this helps.

Comment: 'global' is misleading, they are at the class level.

Comment: Agreed. Marc's answer here is superior. I have made an edit... I though this answer was alright :/

Comment: Marc's answer  is not superior , HE is superior.

Comment: @RoyiNamir not superior - just battle-scarred from having made every mistake a dozen times, and learning from a few of them