# Locking on field or local variable?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, locking

*After I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267323/why-cant-we-lock-on-a-value-type) question with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681356/threading-in-c-sharp-value-types-and-reference-types-clarification) from Marc....*

I sometimes see people locking on a *local* variable.

Is this code broken?

```
public void Do()
{
 object  o  = new Object();
 lock (o)
     {
      ...
     }
}
```

I believe `object  o  = new Object();` should be *outside* the method as a `Field`.

Since each thread is getting a new instance of `o` , there will be multiple locks.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't it lock on fields in this specific case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I believe `object o = new Object();` should be outside the method as a `Field`.
>
> Since each thread is getting a new instance of `o`, there will be
> multiple locks.
>
> What am I missing here? Shouldn't it lock on fields in this specific case?

Your understanding is correct. The code is broken. In this implementation even though lock will be active, it will not provide synchronization as it will be on different objects.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

> When you synchronize thread access to a shared resource, lock on a
> dedicated object instance (for example, private readonly object
> balanceLock = new object();) or another instance that is unlikely to
> be used as a lock object by unrelated parts of the code. Avoid using
> the same lock object instance for different shared resources, as it
> might result in deadlock or lock contention. In particular, avoid
> using the following as lock objects:
>
> this, as it might be used by the callers as a lock. Type instances, as
> those might be obtained by the typeof operator or reflection. string
> instances, including string literals, as those might be interned. Hold
> a lock for as short time as possible to reduce lock contention.

Comment: Shouldnt it depend on what happens inside lock ? If two threads are simply modifying a List that is declared locally, then locking on that local list variable and adding items in it is wrong ?

Comment: @FrankQ. If the list is declared locally, i.e. inside the method, then each thread will have it's own list and the lock becomes pointless anyway. What we have here is a lock that can never have any contenders so all it does is waste performance and cause confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It is broken.

You want a static readonly object as a private field to lock on. As you suspect, your example code creates a new object every time you call Do, and hence the lock will have nothing to hold onto and won't work at all.

```
private static object syncRoot = new object();

lock (syncRoot) { }
```

Comment: it doesnt have to be static. (unless   targeting a different instance)

Comment: making it static readonly does not harm it, only safeguards it (even though it is not required)

Comment: Agreed. It does not have to be static. Depends on what you are protecting.

Comment: [Static or not static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947998/locking-c-sharp-using-private-variables).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the o object every time your method is called.  So, lock won't work. I mean other threads won't wait for the lock to be non signaled and grab control over a resource which this lock controls.  Usually a lock objects is a private variable in a class so that all methods look into the same object.

Answer (score 2):

I, personally, don't see any reason of using this, as `lock` just sets the special field in the *instance* of the `o`, to signaled state. So other threads can check the state of that instance, and based on that execute the code inside the `lock` statement or wait release of it.

Having local variable every time will allocate a new instance, so for every thread it will be ok.

Don't see any meaning in this.

Answer (score 1):

Locking on local variable, the lock won's work.  Locking on global variable can take effect to synchronize multiple thread.

```
using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Threading;

        namespace testLock
        {
            class Program
            {
                public static void Main()
                {
                    // Start a thread that calls a parameterized static method.
                    for(int i = 0; i< 10;i++)
                    {
                        Thread newThread = new Thread(DoWork);
                        newThread.Start(i);
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                static object gObject= new object();
                public static void DoWork(object data)
                {
                    int len = (int)data % 3;
                    object tmp = new object();
                    Console.WriteLine("to lock...... Data='{0}'  sleepTime:{1}", data, len);
                    lock (tmp)//tmp won't work, change tmp to gObject to see different output, which is good locking case)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("in lock...... Data='{0}'  sleepTime:{1}", data, len);

                        Thread.Sleep(  len* 1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Static thread procedure. Data='{0}'  sleepTime:{1}", data, len);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    **Lock temp variable,will output:**
    to lock...... Data='1'  sleepTime:1
    in lock...... Data='1'  sleepTime:1
    to lock...... Data='2'  sleepTime:2
    in lock...... Data='2'  sleepTime:2
    to lock...... Data='0'  sleepTime:0
    in lock...... Data='0'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='0'  sleepTime:0
    to lock...... Data='3'  sleepTime:0
    in lock...... Data='3'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='3'  sleepTime:0
    to lock...... Data='4'  sleepTime:1
    in lock...... Data='4'  sleepTime:1
    to lock...... Data='5'  sleepTime:2
    in lock...... Data='5'  sleepTime:2
    to lock...... Data='6'  sleepTime:0
    in lock...... Data='6'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='6'  sleepTime:0
    to lock...... Data='7'  sleepTime:1
    in lock...... Data='7'  sleepTime:1
    to lock...... Data='8'  sleepTime:2
    in lock...... Data='8'  sleepTime:2
    to lock...... Data='9'  sleepTime:0
    in lock...... Data='9'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='9'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='1'  sleepTime:1
    Static thread procedure. Data='4'  sleepTime:1
    Static thread procedure. Data='7'  sleepTime:1
    Static thread procedure. Data='2'  sleepTime:2
    Static thread procedure. Data='5'  sleepTime:2
    Static thread procedure. Data='8'  sleepTime:2

    **Then lock gObject, will print:**
    to lock...... Data='0'  sleepTime:0
    in lock...... Data='0'  sleepTime:0
    to lock...... Data='1'  sleepTime:1
    to lock...... Data='2'  sleepTime:2
    Static thread procedure. Data='0'  sleepTime:0
    in lock...... Data='1'  sleepTime:1
    to lock...... Data='3'  sleepTime:0
    to lock...... Data='4'  sleepTime:1
    to lock...... Data='5'  sleepTime:2
    to lock...... Data='6'  sleepTime:0
    to lock...... Data='7'  sleepTime:1
    to lock...... Data='8'  sleepTime:2
    to lock...... Data='9'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='1'  sleepTime:1
    in lock...... Data='5'  sleepTime:2
    Static thread procedure. Data='5'  sleepTime:2
    in lock...... Data='9'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='9'  sleepTime:0
    in lock...... Data='2'  sleepTime:2
    Static thread procedure. Data='2'  sleepTime:2
    in lock...... Data='8'  sleepTime:2
    Static thread procedure. Data='8'  sleepTime:2
    in lock...... Data='7'  sleepTime:1
    Static thread procedure. Data='7'  sleepTime:1
    in lock...... Data='4'  sleepTime:1
    Static thread procedure. Data='4'  sleepTime:1
    in lock...... Data='3'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='3'  sleepTime:0
    in lock...... Data='6'  sleepTime:0
    Static thread procedure. Data='6'  sleepTime:0
```

Comment: There are no global variables in C#.

Comment: you are right, the global variable in this example i mean is the static variable in class Program.